# Stacking 'Main lug' load centers for garage

Tags: electrical-panel, nec

I am aware of most NEC codes and am actually asking if this is allowed, There really shouldn't be any reason..I also fully understand keeping my netural and ground seperate and how the bus bars are bridged and grounding case screw etc.

But I could be missing something..And the basic reason for the question..instead of purchasing a larger panel I have a few of these laying around....

I do know you can power the bus bars via a circuit breaker.

Can I also use the actual lugs on that bus bars to send that power to another lug type panel... I do not see why not if connected correctly.

The picture explains pretty clear... I wanna double up the cheapos. They will be connected with 2in+ PVC to which I could never go over my conduit fill. I also am aware there is nothing stopping me from 'butting' them up to one another withe the open holes.
[image: double stacking panels]

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that both hots and neutral must be in the same pipe.

Don't butt them against each other/use bare holes. Set them far enough apart that the covers won’t interfere. Use a **metal** conduit nipple between the panels right wall to left wall. Better yet, use 2-3 sensibly sized ones, so you have an alternate path for crossover wires. If you have 2 metal nipples between them I am very comfortable wiring the ground only to the first one and letting the metal carry the ground to the other.    Can't do that with PVC!

If you use PVC outside, swiff-sand it with a green Scotchbrite pad, prime it with alkyd primer (Kilz will do) and paint it. That protects it from UV.

### If in the same building

You don't need a shutoff switch so don't waste 2 breaker spaces.

You can't put 2 wires on a lug.  But you can get 3-wire Polaris connectors and split.  That's what you do with the hots.  For the neutral and ground, if your buses have room for 2 large wires, just daisy chain.

### If in different buildings

Then you need a shutoff switch.  You can backfeed a double breaker to make a shutoff switch, *if* there is a factory authorized tie-down kit for it to hold it down.

That takes care of the first panel.  For the second panel, just use the feed-thru lugs on the first one to go to the input lugs on the other one,  just as you have planned.  Come to think of it, they are the same lugs, we just changed one's function by back feeding the panel.

Comment: Thank you, you have verified what I have thought.. Yes this is in different building the main service entrance. That is part of why I ask the question; It is required to have a disconnect switch... I do not want to find nor fit a main breaker panel in the hole....
 
"a factory authorized breaker tie-down kit for it to hold it down"

Because the breaker itself is hot and the bus panels. And when I take the panel cover off that is 1) not directly clear nor expected,   2) if the breaker comes free you would have 2 hots hitting the case/ground pretty quick and would be bad